# Scrapy: How to handle if a website is blocked from crawling

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using Scrapy to crawling a website but I got a 404 error. I think the website is blocked from being crawling. How I can manage to bypass that? This is the website I want to crawl `https://tiki.vn/`

And this is the result I got
[image]

Comment: The website is sending you a message. Now you just have to understand it.

Comment: I don't think it shows any meaningful error or message. I had updated the result I got after crawling the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is the request send by me was reject by the website because it's a bot request. I just need to add a custom header to the request and the problem solved

Comment: What was your custom header?